# Script to execute chmod continuously

Tags: shell, solaris, chmod

I am working on Solaris servers. I am using an `ADMIN` user which has all the accesses while other colleagues are using a different user with limited access.
When others want to access the logs I have to manually give `chmod 755` on the log folders and when a new file is generated I have to do `chmod` again.

Is there a way to write a script to run `chmod` continuously every 2 mins on some folders?

Comment: [Every problem is a nail?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)  Instead of actually fixing the *problem* of files being created with permissions that don't suit your needs (perhaps by configuring the logger, or setting it's `umask`), you're adding unneeded complexity.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not a good idea to assign permissions for every 2 min

it's better to change umask of log file owner for create new log file with default 777 permissions

still if you want to use like your idea do like this

1. open crontab
   crontab -e
2. add entry to execute command for every 2 min
   */2 * * * *  chmod -R /path_to_log_folder/
3. save and close
   :wq if it's vi editor
   press x and hit enter if it's nano editor

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [cron](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/sysrescron-24589.html) job.

To setup a `cron` task, run this command as your `ADMIN` user:

```
crontab -e
```

It will open a text editor for you to enter a new job. Write the following line inside the text editor, replace `[file1 file2 ... fileN]` with the files you want to `chmod`, then save. It should run your `chmod` command every 2 minutes.

```
*/2 * * * * chmod 755 [file1 file2 ... fileN]
```

**This first solution doesn't work on every system!** I don't really know about Solaris but if you have a problem with the first format, here is a workaround that will run you command every hour at the minute 0, the minute 2, the minute 4, and so on, until the minute 58:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,3 6,38,40,42,44,46,48,49,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * chmod 755 [file1 file2 ... fileN]
```

You can check that your job was saved correctly with the command `crontab -l` that lists your `cron` tasks.

I invite you to read some documentation on `cron` so that you can understand the format used by `crontab`. [Here is a good link](https://docs.acquia.com/article/cron-time-string-format)

Comment: `*/2` means “every 2 minutes”. `*/5` would mean “every 5 minutes”. `*/30` would mean “every 30 minutes”, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting the `GUID` bit on the containing directory, and setting the group ownership of the directory to a group that these other folks belong to.

That way, any files created in the directory will automatically and always inherit the group of the directory rather than that of the user creating them.

So, in concrete terms, if your log files are in `/var/log/somewhere`, you would do:

```
chmod g+s /var/log/somewhere
chgrp OTHERADMINSGROUP /var/log/somewhere
```

Now test, by creating a file and looking at its group:

```
touch /var/log/somewhere/aFile
ls -l /var/log/somewhere/aFile
```

You should see that the file belongs to OTHERADMINSGROUP rather than your own group.